# Shortcut for properties

Tags: mvvm

I want to create a shortcut or a snippet to create the following two lines with a snippet like when you write propfull then press double tab cause I write these two lines so many times for different fields and different properties

```
  private string name;

  public string Name { get => name; set => SetField(ref name, value); }
```

Comment: That is fine - but what is your question?

Comment: is there any way to create a snippet or a shortcut for these two lines